# Dynamic component event bus not work in vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I just used event bus in vuejs for the dynamic component, but when I emit an event from one component, I cannot listen to that event in another component. Below is the demo I created by codesandbox, what I want to do is output 'test in tes2' from test2component, but it outputs nothing. But when I uncomment the $bus listener in HomeCompnent, the two console.log are all executed.

### main.js

```
Vue.propotype.$bus = new Vue();
```

### HomeComponent

```
<template>
  <div>
    <component :is="currentComponent" @changeComponent="changeComponent"></component>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Test1Component from "./Test1Component";
import Test2Component from "./Test2Component";

export default {
  created() {
    // this.$bus.$on("test", () => console.log("event bus test"));
  },
  components: {
    Test1Component,
    Test2Component
  },
  data() {
    return {
      currentComponent: "Test1Component"
    };
  },
  methods: {
    changeComponent() {
      this.currentComponent = "Test2Component";
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

### Test1Component

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>test1</h1>
    <button @click="changeComponent">click me</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    changeComponent() {
      this.$emit("changeComponent");
      this.$bus.$emit("test");
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

### Test2Component

```
<template>
  <h1>test2</h1>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  created() {
    this.$bus.$on("test", () => console.log("test in test2"));
  }
};
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

[image: Edit Vue Template]

Comment: I downvoted this question because questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Linking to a remote site does not satisfy this requirement as (1. links can break (2. The other site may fail to provide all accessibility tweaks SO has

Comment: @Ferrybig Sorry, I have edited the question

Answer (score 2):

This problem is a good demonstration of the downsides of the event bus pattern:

You, the developer, have to carefully ensure that sender and receiver of all events actually exist at the same moment in time.

In your scenario, that's not the case:

- When Test1Component emits the event, Test2Component doesn't exist yet.
- After Test2Component has been created by HomeComponent just a moment later, the event is already "gone".

My usual disclaimer as a Vue core team member: Don't use the Event bus pattern.

Comment: It seems that I don't understand the event bus pattern. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Event Bus is just fine but problem is in implementation.

You are very correct in case of you `un-comment code` In home component, I tested on your snippet it emit only once `event bus test` [console.log]

> With events you need to take care this

1. You need to define listener. [ make sure you define them before emitting  event ]
2. Now you just emit event. [ to work we need listener to listen first]

In your case you wrote `listener function $on` in `created` event of the`Test2Component`

Now just think for now, You don't have any listeners at beginning as in `home compo` you just commented that listener code .[ its initial step ]

Now when you click on `click me` button you are `changing` component to new component[Test2Component], It is mounted and its `created` event will fire `then this listener will start listening to event`

**but you missed this**

```
this.$emit("changeComponent"); // this is first [ fires/emit ]
this.$bus.$emit("test"); // THEN THIS EMIT
```

> So, When it just start `changing` component from `compo1 to`compo2test`fired/emitted directly without wait, its not`synchronous`it is`**A**synchronous`It will not wait to finish all stuff of`changeComponent`. It will be emitted immediately [`test`]

**Guess what** Now when `test` emits, at that time `Dom operation to add component, ITS NOT DONE YET`, and `test` is emitted

> So, `No listeners are there`, so no `console.log`

But if you see if,  you `UNCOMMENT listener` in home function listener is well defined before `emit of test event` so it output in console.

I hope you understand it, if not let me know point I will explain it in details

> Another thins is that you added $bus in `prototype` so all components has its own bus. instead you can use `GLOBAL event Bus`

as in example you can see.

in es6 you can do

```
//bus.js
const bus = new Vue({});
export default bus;
```

to import it in other components

```
import bus from './bus.js';

// ... do bus.$on ..
// ... do bus.$emit ..
```

```js
var $bus = new Vue({});

Vue.component('Test1', {
 template: `
  <div class="blog-post">
   <h3>test1</h3>
      <button @click="changeComponent">click me</button>
  </div>
 `,
  methods: {
    changeComponent() {
      $bus.$emit("chng");
      $bus.$emit("test");
    }
  }
});

Vue.component('Test2', {
 template: `
  <div class="blog-post">
   <h3>test2</h3>
  </div>
 `,
  created() {
    $bus.$on("test", () => console.log("test in test2 will not fire as we are little late to listen it"));
  }
});


new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 
 created: function(){
  console.log('created');
   $bus.$on("chng", () => this.changeComponent());
   $bus.$on("test", () => console.log("test in test2 main/HOME"));
 },
  data() {
    return {
      currentComponent: "Test1"
    };
  },
  methods: {
    changeComponent() {
      this.currentComponent = "Test2";
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script> console.info = function(){} </script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.js"></script>
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
 <title>Stack Overflow - Hardik Satasiya</title>
 <style>.half{width:50%;float:left;}</style>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="app">
  <component :is="currentComponent" @changeComponent="changeComponent"></component>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your test is not correct.

Basically, `Test2Component` is not created in the time `Test1Component` emit `this.$bus.$emit("test");`

You saw 2 console.log because codesandbox use hot reload modules, so `this.$bus.$on("test", () => console.log("test in test2"));` is still registered if when you change your code.

If you unregister when component destroyed in `Test2Component`, `test in test2` will never be logged

**Test2Component.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>test2</h1>
    <button @click="changeComponent">click me</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  created() {
    console.log("Component 2 is created");
    this.$bus.$on("test", this.testLog);
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    this.$bus.$off("test", this.testLog);
  },
  methods: {
    testLog() {
      console.log("test in test2");
    },
    changeComponent() {
      this.$emit("changeComponent");
    }
  }
};
</script>
<style>

</style>
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/2485jw460y

If you comment

```
  beforeDestroy() {
    this.$bus.$off("test", this.testLog);
  },
```

in component 2, you will see `test in test2` is printed many times after few clicks

(if you change the code, please refresh to run from beginning)